# In SVN is there a straighforward way to merge back each change individually?

Tags: svn, merge

I've got a long-running feature branch that has become incompatible with trunk -- there are lots of binary files that have been modified on both sides so I've got tree conflicts out the wazoo.

In the past when we've run into these issues, we've just diffed the branches against each other, blended in all the changes to trunk using a diff tool, and then committed one huge "All the changes from feature branch" commit. This gets the job done, but because it's not a proper merge we lose the intricate histories of the affected files.

I'd like to try a different route, which is basically a git-style "rebase" but for SVN, where each change is re-applied on top of trunk. **So basically I'm looking for a process for efficiently (i.e. semi-automated) merging every change from the feature branch one-at-a-time back on to trunk and comitting them, so that trunk once again contains the full changelist history.** Can anyone suggest such a process?

I should also mention, I'm on Windows, in case it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible` to find revisions to merge. And then use `svn merge -c  REV` to merge each revision. Also check out the `--accept` option to `merge`.  This may help you resolve issues with conflicting (binary) files automatically.

Comment: So it sounds like I'll have to write a script to do this myself, huh? But this answer provides me with the input I'll need to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you merge in Subversion, you can merge the whole diverged history or only part of it. Latest is so-called "cherry-pick" merge in `svn help merge` and you can cherry-pick even single revision. I hope, you have this way in mind and consecutive `svn merge -c REV` (merge changes from revision REV only) will satisfy your requirements

Answer (score -2):

You can revert each single file sperately to any prior revision
 if this is, what You are looking for.

Comment: How would being able to *revert each single file sperately [sp]* be *efficiently (i.e semi-automated) merging*? There's nothing *efficient* or *semi-automated* about reverting each single file separately.

Comment: You cannot mark multiple files and do this with them?

Comment: That's the question being asked here, which you have failed to answer with your post.

Comment: Try it simply. Mark n files, rightclick context menu, revert to. In terms of answer I provided half complete but still correct answer. Manually choosing revert , the automated part is done by svn.

Comment: There is no mention of TortoiseSVN here (it simply says SVN). SVN is a set of command line tools that don't have a *rightclick context menu* or anything to *mark*. *Half-complete* is not *correct*. If you don't have a *complete* answer, don't post anything, or be prepared to accept the downvotes you receive for doing so.

Comment: Relax dude. I assumed Tortoise implicitely. And I cannot remember complaining about any downvotes at all.